# How to make instant search within wordpress posts?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, search

Today I need to start something special on my website.

I want to create an INSTANT SEARCH which will search within my posts.

A good example is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/users

Another one is: https://sublime.wbond.net/

I don't know from where to start. Any suggestions will be awesome.

PS: I don't need to use any wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No search will ever be 'INSTANT', the closest you will get is searching existing DOM elements.  I'm going to assume you want some kind of AJAX search.

Here are the relevant links

1. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

I assume your going to use jQuery as it seems in this situation there is no need not to (no need to reinvent the wheel), a couple of google searches will take you a long way as there is a lot of information on this subject and a good amount of tutorials out there.

The basic outline of the process is below

1. User enters input
2. This fires an ajax request
3. Server receives POST/GET values and performs a search
4. Server now outputs that data in a JSON format or pre-rendered HTML
5. The javascript will receive this data and render it (if JSON) into HTML or append the pre-rendered HTML to some element.

If you need some more direction let me know.